# Angular, TypeError: _this.tasks.unshift is not a function

Tags: angular

When creating a task in the console, this error appears.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.tasks.unshift is not a function
TypeError: _this.tasks.unshift is not a function
at form.ts:62
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3654)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
at zone.js:872
```

In the terminal there is this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/tasks/form.ts(62,26): error TS2345: Argument of type 'void | Task' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Task'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Task'.
```

form.ts

```
59  createTask() {
60  this._taskService.create(this.createTaskForm.value)
61  .then(data => {
62    this.tasks.unshift(data);
63    this._taskService.tasks.next(this.tasks);
64    this.resetForm();
65  });
66  }
```

Comment: where do u initialize \the `this.tasks`

Comment: Maybe you have two different types with the same name?